# Append Py Pandas Dataframes into a single .csv, iterating by separate list

Tags: python, csv, pandas, iteration, dataframe

I'm attempting to use pandas to join content from three separate flat files into a single .csv.  One of the output fields, 'StoreID', is based on a separate list of ID values ('Stores.txt').  In essence, I need to publish a merged dataframe as a series of csv rows, while at the same time appending results for each store ID in a third column.  I'm having trouble with iteration syntax.  Any help would be most appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd

items = pd.read_csv("Item_List.csv")
store_loc = pd.read_csv("Store_Locations.csv")
stores = open("Stores.txt")

for i in stores:
    item_merged = items.merge(store_loc, on='itemCat')
    item_merged['storeID'] = i
item_merged.to_csv("stores_items_output.csv", index=False)
```

Hypothetical Stores.txt:

```
3
5
6
```

Desired Output, given a joined list of items and locations:

```
itemID,storeLocation,StoreID
12345,ABCDE,3
23456,ABCDE,3
34567,BCDEF,3
12345,ABCDE,5
23456,ABCDE,5
34567,BCDEF,5
12345,ABCDE,6
23456,ABCDE,6
34567,BCDEF,6
```

Comment: it sounds like what you are trying to do is duplicate the combined dfs of itemID and storeLocation with each StoreID, correct? it'd be better to concat them but set the 'StoreID' prior to the concatenation, at the moment you are overwriting each merge with the last set operation so all your rows will have the same 'storeID'. I'd just create a temp df or the intial merge, set the 'storeID' column and then either merge or concat to your item_merged' df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying, the problem in your code is that you overwrite the store id with the last value so they'll all have the same store id.

What you appear to want is 3 dfs where you have 3 permutations of store id for each merged items and locations.

My approach would be to merge outside the loop, make a temp df that is a **copy**, set the storeId for this df and concat to your merged df and then write out to a csv:

```
# our merged items and store locations
merged_items = items.merge(store_loc, on='itemCat')
for i in stores:
    # take a copy
    temp_df = merged_items.copy()
    # set the store id
    temp_df['storeID'] = i
    # now just concat
    item_merged = pd.concat([iterm_merged, temp_df], ignore_index=True)

# rest of code is same
```

Comment: Thanks, Ed.  In reality, I'm looking at n storeID values (in the 100s).  The intent is to loop & concat all itemID to StoreLocation pairs for every 1 storeID

Comment: You would be better off appending to a list first and then concatenating them using pandas, it will be very inefficient looping in this way and concatenating them.